# Subdomains on VMs to all go through port 80 using Windows Server

Tags: virtual-machine, dns, webserver, docker, container

Right so I have been trying to set up the following and failed so far :-)
Some settings are out of my control, so I need to work with what I have got and hope that this is still possible.

**My Scenario**

The following things are beyond my control - as in I cannot change them

- I have a DNS server running on Windows Server 2012 R2
- I cannot change any firewall ports without making specific requests, so I would like to keep this to a minimum

On a different IP address, which I can link any machine to I have port 80 open. Currently this is being used by an VM running Ubuntu.

**What I want to do**

What I want to achieve is running multiple VMs and link them to a subdomain and have those subdomains pointed to those VMs on my network so that they can run their own webserver instance.

This subdomains have to be accessible from the outside - so not just locally on my own network.

So far I have tried installing bind9 on the ubuntu machine, but I think having 2 DNS servers is doing me less favours. The main DNS server can only point to one IP address that has port 80 exposed, so somehow I need the subdomains to point to that server as and resolve those subdomain names to the outside.

Now these subdomains need to come from other virtual machines - not just multiple websites on a single machine.

**Why?**

I want to test out different machine settings and have them run a website.
I eventually want to use containers like docker, but I have needs beyond that. Unless a container can point to a subdomain?

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no problem to run your own DNS locally to override resolving provided by w2k8, just use only one DNS, not both. If you install `nginx` for example in one of your VM you can set it up as reverse proxy for your other VMs. This way `nginx` accepting all connection on port 80 and forward connection to particular VM base on subdomain names. If you need to allow access to your setup by subdomain names from internet you need to setup external DNS know to the world that will point your subdomains to your external IP

Comment: I found some blogs and instructions on that so I will have a look